# how to create a dataframe from relational database with sparse columns in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to read some data from a relational database to do some machine learning in Spark. However, the table I have to read has some sparse columns. Also, it has a column called "SpecialPurposeColumns" which contains non-zero data in XML format, like:

```
<Age>76</Age><ID>78</ID><Income>87000</Income> ... <ZIP>96733</ZIP>
```

what is the good way to create a dataframe in spark using this data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's classical RDMS reading with SQLContext. And also what did you try so far ? What's the issue you are encountering ?

Comment: @eliasah I have tried to export data as csv file and uploaded to hdfs and read it in spark. The issue is this "SpecialPurposeColumns" column only has the feature which is not zero.